# Access X-window and sound on laptop on another Unix

Tags: ssh, remote, raspberry-pi, x-server

I have a Rasberry Pi running archarm hooked up to a TV. Because it is lacking power for some jobs (e.g. watching large flash videos), I want to kind of compute them on my laptop and send the X output to my Pi. I tried some tutorials on the net without success. I think that my laptop is the `server` or `remote-machine`, and the pi the `client`. So I enabled `X11Forwarding` in /etc/ssh/sshd_config on the Laptop issued `xhost +` and restarted the service. After that I used `ssh -X user@laptop_ip` to connect. As I issued `startx`, the Display on my LAPTOP started a new xfce session.

Do I understand the concept wrong? How can I make the Pi act as a remote machine, so that they both share the screen from the laptop?

Comment: remote X isn't going to be suitable for video streaming.

Comment: If you have not already looked at it: omxplayer. Plays all movies with more ease than my desktop systems.

Answer (score 2):

Video streaming is data-heavy, which is why recorded videos are encoded and compressed to begin with.  If you have a low-latency (relatively) high bandwidth LAN between the Pi and the laptop it is possible, but your main problem will be with the sound.

If you ssh into the laptop from the Pi using something along the lines of 
`ssh -nq laptop "xine moviefile"` you will get the application on the Pi, BUT the sound will still be pushed out the laptop sound channel.  There is no X standard for sound streaming.

Comment: Additional note - the nomenclature for X-server and client are reversed from the normal expectation.  The "server" is the desktop you operate from, the "client" is the application.  This is correct in terms of client/server operations because it is the application making the request for services (display, keyboard, mouse, etc.), and the desktop providing those resources.

Comment: While technically correct regarding sound, there are third-party tools which can effectively do this, eg, PulseAudio.

Comment: so the apps on the laptop are `client` like `xine` and have to be installed on the laptop, while my pi is providing the server part of X?

Comment: @Rafael That is correct.